# Android lifecycle of thread-based game

Tags: android, lifecycle

I ran into a bit of trouble while trying to get my game to work correctly after being put to the background by the user or a phone call for example.

My app has a SurfaceView class called GameView, which has the onDraw() method to do all the necessary drawing for my game and two threads - one for calling the onDraw() and one for doing the necessary calculations for the game's logic.

I succesfully implemented onPause() and onResume(). (I paused both threads when back button was pressed and resumed them after user cancelled in the AlertDialog.)

Now I would like to have the game paused the same way when onStop() gets called. I put both threads on pause and saved my characters location in the savedInstanceState, but when I start my app again, no method gets called (I checked with Logcat). I believe onRestart() should be called first, then onStart() and then onResume(), but none of that happens. What am I doing wrong?

(Didn't include any code, because it seems to be a problem of me not understanding the lifecycle, not a problem in code. If it seems necessary, I'll post the parts you request.)

Comment: At least onResume() must be called if the user comes back to your game. Are you 100% sure that onResume is not called?. You can compare your understanding of the lifecycle with the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: No methods get called according to LogCat, is it possible the game crashes before these methods get called? Maybe it has already crashed when user minimizes the app? When I start the app again, it shows me the same picture I saw when closing it, but it is totally unresponsive.

Comment: A crash should show up in your logs. Unresponsiveness indicates that something is blocking your main thread. Maybe the blocking code prevents the onResume() method to get executed. Try to put log messages or breakpoints at the top of your onResume() and onCreate() method. Even before calling super.onResume() and super.onCreate().

Comment: When I turn off the screen, it calls onPause() and onStop().
When I use the home button to minimize, it just calls onPause().
But when I restore it, nothing gets called, I put the Logs before super. calls...

Comment: That is perfectly fine. The decision, to only pause, or pause and stop your activity is up to android. Something must be called on restore ... or you wouldn't see anything :). Maybe you should use the debugger and breakpoints to analyze what happens.